# Javascript/Jquery - no me toma string con espacios en blanco

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function MostrarDatos() {
    //traigo los datos del select, y los muestro en un textbox
    var valorSelSec = $('#slcSecciones option:selected').val();
    var valorSelCat = $('#slcCategorias option:selected').val();
    var valorSelEst = $('#slcEstilos option:selected').val();
    //marcas es donde me sale el error, por ej tengo una marca: north sails.. pero me muestra north y no 
    //toma el valor
    var valorSelMarc = $('#slcMarcas option:selected').val();
    var valorSelTall = $('#slcTalles option:selected').val();

    $("#txtSecRes").val(valorSelSec);
    $("#txtCatRes").val(valorSelCat);
    $("#txtEstRes").val(valorSelEst);
    $("#txtMarcRes").val(valorSelMarc);
    $("#txtTallRes").val(valorSelTall);
}

//obtengo las marcas de la base de datos mediante un ajax
function DesplegarMarca(NombreSeccion, NombreCategoria, NombreEstilo) {
    $("#slcMarcas").html('<option selected disabled>Seleccione una opcion...</option>');
    var dir = "CargoMarca";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: api + dir + "?NombreSeccion=" + NombreSeccion + "&NombreCategoria=" + NombreCategoria + "&NombreEstilo=" + NombreEstilo + " ",
        success: function(marca) {
            var mar = marca;
            for (var i = 0; i < mar.length; i++) {
                // if (!$('#slcMarcas').val()) {
                //   $("#slcMarcas").append("<option>" + "No hay marcas disponibles" + "</option>")
                // }
                $("#slcMarcas").append("<option value=" + mar[i] + " >" + mar[i] + "</option>")
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }

    });
}
```

Tengo un problema, tengo un select dinamico que traigo nombres de una base de datos, de esos nombres, algunos tienen espacio en blanco, por ej: "un nombre"
Lo que ocurre es que cuando quiero mostrar ese nombre, o hacer una accion con el, no me lo toma porque cuando entra en la posicion del espacio en blanco, se queda ahi, y no lo termina de leer...

en base de datos : "un nombre"...

cuando lo selecciono en select y lo muestro(por ej), me muestra : "un"...

No se que hacer, porque quitarle el espacio en blanco queda mal, porque quedaria "unnombre"

Comment: Preguntas que no contienen el avance de tu problema pueden cerrarse, te aconsejo leas [ask] y [mcve] para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Saludos es mejor si agregas tu código para poder darte una mejor respuesta y posible solución..!!

Comment: Ahi lo agregue !

Comment: Hola, dentro del append te faltan las comillas para el `"<option value=" + mar[i] + " >"`, deberia ser `` "<option value='" + mar[i] + "' >"`, eso es todo.

Comment: muchas gracias, nunca me iba a dar cuenta que era eso! Y aun sigo sin entender por que! pero funciono, gracias

Comment: Escribe tu comentario como respuesta para que quede registrada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de nada darte la bienvenida a la comunidad!

Inicialmente realicé una respuesta y cohincide con la solución en el comentario que he visto un poco mas tarde. El mal uso o falta de comillas.

Explico y doy algunas recomendaciones del porque de este tipo de cosas.

Lo primero referencia al los tipos de secuencias de escapado de código en PHP:
https://phppot.com/php/php-escape-sequences/

Por otro a la documentación de blade
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade

En la doccumentación de blade, se pueden ver algunos "Notice o Alertas" de como se deben utilizar las comillas en función de las directivas que usemos o del tipo de datos a tratar.
De ahí la importancia de las excepciones en la documentación, es lo que nos permite conocer el código internamente sin ir a mirar la línea de código y entender que hace.

Ejemplo: Con la directiva @json para convertir los datos ES NECESARIO, utilizar comillas simples.

Esto es, por como está hecho laravel junto a blade y como estos procesan los datos internamente.

Por otro lado, se dan algunas recomendaciones como realizar expresiones correctamente en blade según el caso si estás manejando strings o datos con caractéres especiales y tratar correctamente el escapado

Por último y no menos importante, te recomiendo esto para tratar "plantillas blade con Javascript". Permite gestionar de una forma mas simple y cómoda, a la vez segura, las variables que se comunican entre "php blade y javascript". Creo que es interesante
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-blade-javascript

Si por tu versión de laravel no puedes hacer uso del módulo, te invito a observar este código y quizás puedas realizar un módulo para ti que haga algo similar.

Espero que te ayude y sirva para entender mejor el tema del tratamiento de datos entre javascript y php.

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta me ha servido de mucho!